# Alexa Called Lambda Function that Queries MySQL database loops forever

Tags: mysql, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

When I try running the following lambda function I get the appropriate value added to my MySQL database, however, the Alexa skill outputs an error and trying to delete the value from my database shows that it immediately gets added again forever until I change the name of the table (then I guess it errors and eventually stops).

I have the MySQL bit firing when I call any Alexa Intent from my skill.  I don't know callbacks and Alexa contexts that well, so I imagine I'm doing something incorrect handling those. It seems like the query command is getting called many times, which I don't understand since at the end of every callback "route" I have either context.succeeds or context.fails, which should end my Lambda function and give Alexa what it needs to continue with the output needed by the skill.

Here's my current code:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: '-',
    user: '-',
    password: '-',
    database: '-'
});

exports.handler = (event, context) => {
    try {

        if (event.session.new) {
            // New Session
            console.log("NEW SESSION");
        }


        switch (event.request.type) {

            case "LaunchRequest":
                // Launch Request
                console.log(`LAUNCH REQUEST`);
                context.succeed(
                    generateResponse({},
                        buildSpeechletResponse("Welcome to an Alexa Skill, this is running on a deployed lamda function", true)
                    )
                );
                break;

            case "IntentRequest":
                // Intent Request
                console.log(`Intent Request`);
                console.log('Then run MySQL code:');
                connection.connect(function(err) {
                    console.log('Inside connection.connect() callback');
                    if (!err) {
                        console.log("Database is connected ... ");
                        connection.query("INSERT INTO Users (user_id) VALUES ('TESTNAME')",
                            function(err2, result) {
                                console.log("Inside connection.query() callback");
                                if (!err2) {
                                    console.log("Query Successful! Ending Connection.");
                                    connection.end(function(err3) {
                                        if (!err3) {
                                            console.log("Connection ended!")
                                            context.succeed(
                                                generateResponse({},
                                                    buildSpeechletResponse("Welcome to the incredible intelligent MySQLable Alexa!", true)
                                                )
                                            );
                                        } else {
                                            console.log("Ending connection failure!");
                                            context.fail("Ending connection failure! " + err3.message);
                                        }
                                    });
                                } else {
                                    connection.end(function(err3) {
                                        if (!err3) {
                                            console.log("Query error! Ending Connection!");
                                            context.fail(`Query error! Ending Connection!` + err2.message);
                                        } else {
                                            console.log("Query error and Error ending connection!" + err2.message + " " + err3.message);
                                            context.fail("Query error and Error ending connection!" + err2.message + " " + err3.message);
                                        }
                                    });
                                }
                            });
                    } else {
                        console.log("Error connecting database3 ..." + err.message);
                        context.fail("Error connecting database3 ... " + err.message);
                    }
                });

                break;

            case "SessionEndedRequest":
                // Session Ended Request
                console.log(`SESSION ENDED REQUEST`);
                break;

            default:
                context.fail(`INVALID REQUEST TYPE: ${event.request.type}`);

        }

    } catch (error) {
        context.fail(`Exception: ${error}`);
    }

};

//Helpers
buildSpeechletResponse = (outputText, shouldEndSession) => {

    return {
        outputSpeech: {
            type: "PlainText",
            text: outputText
        },
        shouldEndSession: shouldEndSession
    };
};

generateResponse = (sessionAttributes, speechletResponse) => {
    return {
        version: "1.0",
        sessionAttributes: sessionAttributes,
        response: speechletResponse
    };
};
```

Edit: Adding my last two execution logs for this function from CloudWatch (2 because they have different things going on, even though I didn't change the code):
Log 1:

```
START RequestId: 95d48cfa-05d4-11e7-9155-f97c8b68d7d5 Version: $LATEST
2017-03-10T21:00:26.498Z    95d48cfa-05d4-11e7-9155-f97c8b68d7d5    Intent Request
2017-03-10T21:00:26.499Z    95d48cfa-05d4-11e7-9155-f97c8b68d7d5    Then run MySQL code:
2017-03-10T21:00:26.728Z    95d48cfa-05d4-11e7-9155-f97c8b68d7d5    Inside connection.connect() callback
2017-03-10T21:00:26.728Z    95d48cfa-05d4-11e7-9155-f97c8b68d7d5    Database is connected ... 
2017-03-10T21:00:26.777Z    95d48cfa-05d4-11e7-9155-f97c8b68d7d5    Inside connection.query() callback
2017-03-10T21:00:26.777Z    95d48cfa-05d4-11e7-9155-f97c8b68d7d5    Query Successful! Ending Connection.
2017-03-10T21:00:26.810Z    95d48cfa-05d4-11e7-9155-f97c8b68d7d5    Connection ended!
END RequestId: 95d48cfa-05d4-11e7-9155-f97c8b68d7d5
REPORT RequestId: 95d48cfa-05d4-11e7-9155-f97c8b68d7d5  Duration: 323.15 ms Billed Duration: 400 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 21 MB  
START RequestId: a024a0f8-05d4-11e7-966a-f5772bbe4b76 Version: $LATEST
2017-03-10T21:00:43.598Z    a024a0f8-05d4-11e7-966a-f5772bbe4b76    NEW SESSION
2017-03-10T21:00:43.598Z    a024a0f8-05d4-11e7-966a-f5772bbe4b76    Intent Request
2017-03-10T21:00:43.598Z    a024a0f8-05d4-11e7-966a-f5772bbe4b76    Then run MySQL code:
2017-03-10T21:00:43.599Z    a024a0f8-05d4-11e7-966a-f5772bbe4b76    Inside connection.connect() callback
2017-03-10T21:00:43.599Z    a024a0f8-05d4-11e7-966a-f5772bbe4b76    Error connecting database ...Cannot enqueue Handshake after invoking quit.
2017-03-10T21:00:43.599Z    a024a0f8-05d4-11e7-966a-f5772bbe4b76
{
    "errorMessage": "Error connecting database ... Cannot enqueue Handshake after invoking quit."
}

END RequestId: a024a0f8-05d4-11e7-966a-f5772bbe4b76
REPORT RequestId: a024a0f8-05d4-11e7-966a-f5772bbe4b76  Duration: 1.64 ms   Billed Duration: 100 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 21 MB  
START RequestId: 18780091-05d5-11e7-bfda-d5b48281dc76 Version: $LATEST
2017-03-10T21:04:05.517Z    18780091-05d5-11e7-bfda-d5b48281dc76    Intent Request
2017-03-10T21:04:05.518Z    18780091-05d5-11e7-bfda-d5b48281dc76    Then run MySQL code:
2017-03-10T21:04:05.518Z    18780091-05d5-11e7-bfda-d5b48281dc76    Inside connection.connect() callback
2017-03-10T21:04:05.518Z    18780091-05d5-11e7-bfda-d5b48281dc76    Error connecting database ...Cannot enqueue Handshake after invoking quit.
2017-03-10T21:04:05.518Z    18780091-05d5-11e7-bfda-d5b48281dc76
{
    "errorMessage": "Error connecting database ... Cannot enqueue Handshake after invoking quit."
}

END RequestId: 18780091-05d5-11e7-bfda-d5b48281dc76
REPORT RequestId: 18780091-05d5-11e7-bfda-d5b48281dc76  Duration: 1.16 ms   Billed Duration: 100 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 21 MB  
START RequestId: 611a846e-05d5-11e7-9fa7-4db18c46269c Version: $LATEST
2017-03-10T21:06:07.372Z    611a846e-05d5-11e7-9fa7-4db18c46269c    NEW SESSION
2017-03-10T21:06:07.372Z    611a846e-05d5-11e7-9fa7-4db18c46269c    LAUNCH REQUEST
END RequestId: 611a846e-05d5-11e7-9fa7-4db18c46269c
REPORT RequestId: 611a846e-05d5-11e7-9fa7-4db18c46269c  Duration: 0.53 ms   Billed Duration: 100 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 21 MB  
START RequestId: 6dea8c27-05d5-11e7-975a-b7ed1b69129a Version: $LATEST
2017-03-10T21:06:28.837Z    6dea8c27-05d5-11e7-975a-b7ed1b69129a    NEW SESSION
2017-03-10T21:06:28.837Z    6dea8c27-05d5-11e7-975a-b7ed1b69129a    LAUNCH REQUEST
END RequestId: 6dea8c27-05d5-11e7-975a-b7ed1b69129a
REPORT RequestId: 6dea8c27-05d5-11e7-975a-b7ed1b69129a  Duration: 0.48 ms   Billed Duration: 100 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 21 MB  
START RequestId: 7d9551ae-05d5-11e7-8022-19fa614b0eec Version: $LATEST
2017-03-10T21:06:55.113Z    7d9551ae-05d5-11e7-8022-19fa614b0eec    NEW SESSION
2017-03-10T21:06:55.113Z    7d9551ae-05d5-11e7-8022-19fa614b0eec    Intent Request
2017-03-10T21:06:55.113Z    7d9551ae-05d5-11e7-8022-19fa614b0eec    Then run MySQL code:
2017-03-10T21:06:55.113Z    7d9551ae-05d5-11e7-8022-19fa614b0eec    Inside connection.connect() callback
2017-03-10T21:06:55.113Z    7d9551ae-05d5-11e7-8022-19fa614b0eec    Error connecting database ...Cannot enqueue Handshake after invoking quit.
2017-03-10T21:06:55.113Z    7d9551ae-05d5-11e7-8022-19fa614b0eec
{
    "errorMessage": "Error connecting database ... Cannot enqueue Handshake after invoking quit."
}

END RequestId: 7d9551ae-05d5-11e7-8022-19fa614b0eec
REPORT RequestId: 7d9551ae-05d5-11e7-8022-19fa614b0eec  Duration: 0.58 ms   Billed Duration: 100 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 21 MB  
START RequestId: d88642f3-05d5-11e7-922f-7554077e1300 Version: $LATEST
2017-03-10T21:09:27.700Z    d88642f3-05d5-11e7-922f-7554077e1300    NEW SESSION
2017-03-10T21:09:27.700Z    d88642f3-05d5-11e7-922f-7554077e1300    Intent Request
2017-03-10T21:09:27.700Z    d88642f3-05d5-11e7-922f-7554077e1300    Then run MySQL code:
2017-03-10T21:09:27.700Z    d88642f3-05d5-11e7-922f-7554077e1300    Inside connection.connect() callback
2017-03-10T21:09:27.700Z    d88642f3-05d5-11e7-922f-7554077e1300    Error connecting database ...Cannot enqueue Handshake after invoking quit.
2017-03-10T21:09:27.700Z    d88642f3-05d5-11e7-922f-7554077e1300
{
    "errorMessage": "Error connecting database ... Cannot enqueue Handshake after invoking quit."
}

END RequestId: d88642f3-05d5-11e7-922f-7554077e1300
REPORT RequestId: d88642f3-05d5-11e7-922f-7554077e1300  Duration: 0.64 ms   Billed Duration: 100 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 21 MB  
START RequestId: 2f22a7f9-05d6-11e7-aa88-9f42daad4e3b Version: $LATEST
2017-03-10T21:11:53.020Z    2f22a7f9-05d6-11e7-aa88-9f42daad4e3b    NEW SESSION
2017-03-10T21:11:53.020Z    2f22a7f9-05d6-11e7-aa88-9f42daad4e3b    Intent Request
2017-03-10T21:11:53.020Z    2f22a7f9-05d6-11e7-aa88-9f42daad4e3b    Then run MySQL code:
2017-03-10T21:11:53.020Z    2f22a7f9-05d6-11e7-aa88-9f42daad4e3b    Inside connection.connect() callback
2017-03-10T21:11:53.020Z    2f22a7f9-05d6-11e7-aa88-9f42daad4e3b    Error connecting database ...Cannot enqueue Handshake after invoking quit.
2017-03-10T21:11:53.020Z    2f22a7f9-05d6-11e7-aa88-9f42daad4e3b
{
    "errorMessage": "Error connecting database ... Cannot enqueue Handshake after invoking quit."
}

END RequestId: 2f22a7f9-05d6-11e7-aa88-9f42daad4e3b
REPORT RequestId: 2f22a7f9-05d6-11e7-aa88-9f42daad4e3b  Duration: 0.67 ms   Billed Duration: 100 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 21 MB
```

Log 2:

```
START RequestId: 4dba3aa0-05d6-11e7-85fc-d115fdc4ab9e Version: $LATEST
2017-03-10T21:12:44.518Z    4dba3aa0-05d6-11e7-85fc-d115fdc4ab9e    NEW SESSION
2017-03-10T21:12:44.519Z    4dba3aa0-05d6-11e7-85fc-d115fdc4ab9e    Intent Request
2017-03-10T21:12:44.519Z    4dba3aa0-05d6-11e7-85fc-d115fdc4ab9e    Then run MySQL code:
2017-03-10T21:12:44.756Z    4dba3aa0-05d6-11e7-85fc-d115fdc4ab9e    Inside connection.connect() callback
2017-03-10T21:12:44.756Z    4dba3aa0-05d6-11e7-85fc-d115fdc4ab9e    Database is connected ... 
2017-03-10T21:12:44.799Z    4dba3aa0-05d6-11e7-85fc-d115fdc4ab9e    Inside connection.query() callback
2017-03-10T21:12:44.838Z    4dba3aa0-05d6-11e7-85fc-d115fdc4ab9e    Query error! Ending Connection!
2017-03-10T21:12:44.838Z    4dba3aa0-05d6-11e7-85fc-d115fdc4ab9e
{
    "errorMessage": "Query error! Ending Connection!ER_DUP_ENTRY: Duplicate entry 'TESTNAME' for key 'PRIMARY'"
}

END RequestId: 4dba3aa0-05d6-11e7-85fc-d115fdc4ab9e
REPORT RequestId: 4dba3aa0-05d6-11e7-85fc-d115fdc4ab9e  Duration: 333.25 ms Billed Duration: 400 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 21 MB  
START RequestId: ffd37e18-05d6-11e7-bdde-15cef47016ee Version: $LATEST
2017-03-10T21:17:43.197Z    ffd37e18-05d6-11e7-bdde-15cef47016ee    NEW SESSION
2017-03-10T21:17:43.197Z    ffd37e18-05d6-11e7-bdde-15cef47016ee    Intent Request
2017-03-10T21:17:43.197Z    ffd37e18-05d6-11e7-bdde-15cef47016ee    Then run MySQL code:
2017-03-10T21:17:43.197Z    ffd37e18-05d6-11e7-bdde-15cef47016ee    Inside connection.connect() callback
2017-03-10T21:17:43.197Z    ffd37e18-05d6-11e7-bdde-15cef47016ee    Error connecting database3 ...Cannot enqueue Handshake after invoking quit.
2017-03-10T21:17:43.198Z    ffd37e18-05d6-11e7-bdde-15cef47016ee
{
    "errorMessage": "Error connecting database3 ... Cannot enqueue Handshake after invoking quit."
}

END RequestId: ffd37e18-05d6-11e7-bdde-15cef47016ee
REPORT RequestId: ffd37e18-05d6-11e7-bdde-15cef47016ee  Duration: 5.65 ms   Billed Duration: 100 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 21 MB
```

Comment: Take a look at the cloudwatch logs for the function.  Is it being invoked multiple times, or just once?  What do the logs tell you?

Comment: I added my last two error logs.  It certainly seems like some of the code is getting run > once.

Comment: If you really want to disconnect from the database inside the handler, move `var connection = mysql.createConnection` inside the handler.  Variables outside the handler **may** (not **will** -- they **may**) persist from one invocation to the next (see "container reuse"), and you're thus trying to reuse a connection you've disconnected.

Comment: Any idea why it's failing the first time and triggering the looping behavior?

Comment: I've removed my comment about the duplicate RequestID.  My eyeball parser misfired on that.  I only see that once.

Comment: It appears to be working the very first time, then failing after that.  Move the `var connection ...` inside the handler and troubleshoot from there.

Comment: Is it safe to just stick the `require` and the `var connection ...` above the `try` block right after the definition for the handler starts?

Comment: You could do that, but right after `case "IntentRequest":` appears to be the only place you'd need it at first glance.

Comment: That seems to have partially worked.  My Alexa Skill now can be called (for example, by speaking to my Echo and asking for any invocation).

The problem now seems to be that when I test the Lambda code, it doesn't repeat the command, but when I use Alexa to invoke the Lambda code it gets run repeatedly until I change the name of my Table.